# How do I ingest geojson in Geomesa?

Tags: geomesa

I'm trying to ingest a geojson file like this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id_trip": 1547,
                "starttime": "2017-09-18 04:16:58UTC",
                "endtime": "2017-09-18 04:26:26UTC"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiLineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -73.651166,
                            45.544501
                        ],
                        [
                            -73.651227,
                            45.544519
                        ],
.....
```

I added a simplefeaturetype:

```
"trajet"={attributes=[{ name = "id_trip", type = "String" }{ name = "starttime",  type = "Date" }{ name = "endtime", type = "Date" }{ name = "geom",    type = "MultiLineString" }]}
```

Because geomesa couldn't guess the converter, I defined the following converter:

```
geomesa.converters.geoconv = {
  type         = "geojson"
  id-field     = "$id_trip"
  feature-path = "$.Features[*]"
  fields = [
    { name = "id_trip",      json-type = "integer",  path = "$.id_trip",               transform = "toString($0)"                }
    { name = "starttime",    json-type = "date",   path = "$.starttime",                               }
    { name = "endtime",     json-type = "date",  path = "$.endtime",                                              }
    { name = "geom",    json-type = "geometry", path = "$.geom",  transform = "multilinestring($0)" }
  ]
}
```

I get a fatal error with 0% complete 0 ingested 0 failed in 00:00:00

Thanks for suggestions.

Edited: 
I actually winded up using SHP file instead, I dont know why, but it was ingested without any error.

Comment: did you get this working? It would be helpful to others who might find the post if you add your solution as an answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found an other format of my data in SHP, it is was worked with me at the end

Answer (score 0):

Even though you decided to go with SHP file the main problem was probably with your converter or specification. Its not that trivial to generate them (at least for me) therefore they have inferred way to generate them (look like you did not make it working) therefore try to following:

```
# DONT specify --spec or -c    
geomesa-kafka ingest -z localhost:2181 -b localhost:9092 --input-format json -f test-ingestion /Users/krivva/Documents/data/geojsons/units_pooling.geojson
```

If will then should detect the schema (if the file is syntactically valid):

[image]

Persist it, give it decent names for spec sand converter and you should be good to go.